# discord.py not detecting rich presence

Tags: python, discord.py

im having trouble with this bit of code for my discord bot its suppose to detect a person playing a specific game and then send a message in a channel, but its not detecting nor sending

heres my code so far:

```
@client.event
async def get_all_members(channel):
    games = ["osu!"] 
    #add code later to make ping work
    if channel.activity and channel.activity.name.lower() in games:
        channel;client.get.channel(804884691328303115)
        await channel.send("playing osu is not ok")
```

if anyone can help that will be very much appreciated, thanks

Comment: This code is very broken. What does `channel.activity` do? What is `channel;client.get.channel` supposed to do? What is `get_all_members` doing as an event? Stack Overflow is mainly meant for individual problems in the code that can be reliably reproduced. [MRE]

Answer (score 0):

First off, this looks like a typo

```py
channel;client.get.channel(804884691328303115)
```

Looks like it should be

```py
channel = client.get.channel(804884691328303115)
```

Next, `Channel.activity` is not a thing. I assume you're looking for something like `Member.activity`. You'll have to loop through all members & check each of their activities.

Lastly, if you want to have access to people's precenses/activities, you need the Presence Intent. For proper accuracy when getting the members you'll also need the Members Intent.

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Make sure to enable it both in code & in your application on the Discord Developers dashboard.

Comment: While all of these are true, this question needs debugging details and thus shouldn't be answered. Why would this code not raise errors if `Channel.activity` didn't exist? Ah, because the OP is trying to use an event called `get_all_members` which obviously does not exist. Essentially all this answer does is debug someone's code, which isn't the purpose of SO. The purpose of SO is to answer *questions*.